# uwsgi : doesn't detect plugins

Tags: python, plugins, uwsgi

In Ubuntu i installed uwsgi and then the plugins with the following commands :

```
$ sudo apt-get install uwsgi
$ sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3
$ sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
```

When i kill the process of uwsgi and rerun uwsgi with the following commands in a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '********* kill instance ******************'
sudo kill -HUP `cat /tmp/sup-epa.pid`
uwsgi --reload /tmp/sup-epa.pid
sudo touch /tmp/sup.epa.sock

uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/
```

The output is :

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WARNING !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
no request plugin is loaded, you will not be able to manage requests.
you may need to install the package for your language of choice, or simply load it with --plugin.
!!!!!!!!!!! END OF WARNING !!!!!!!!!!
```

But in fact the uwsgi configuration file has it :

```
[uwsgi]
plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
plugin = python3
```

The best aproach according to the manual is to put the parameters in one ini file and then load it with the ini. Should i run the uwsgi with path of plugin and then put the --plugin parameter ?

Comment: [Please read this and do step by step](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Install.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ini file with emperor mode without problem.

With the distro packages you have installed you should specify `plugin = python`. There is no need of plugin-dir here. You may not use `plugin = pythonXX` unless you want to specify wich version of python you want to use. But you need aditional conf if you want to do this this way. See the [quickstart for python](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html) chapter "Bonus: multiple Python versions for the same uWSGI binary".

Or you can specify a fixed version with something like: `sudo update-alternatives --set uwsgi /usr/bin/uwsgi_python27`. Provided that the version you want is installed `sudo update-alternatives --list uwsgi`